# Merging two tables into an existing third table with CROSS JOIN -

Tags: mysql, sql

**User_Details** with User_ID, Status (1/0), Name, etc.

**Regions**, with three regions: US, Europe, Asia, with respective ID# 1,2, and 3.

**User_Region_Mapping** that map User_ID with Region_ID that give access to different regions which contains User_ID, Region_ID, and Status (1/0)

I am trying to create a query that adds every single region to every single  ACTIVE(aka status = 1) user, avoiding redundant data points that already exist in the User_Region_Mapping table (leaving the existing data there).

So every single active user ID has three rows, with region IDs 1,2,3, where status is set to 1 for all of them, because status cannot be null.
I know I have to use a combination of CROSS JOIN and LEFT JOIN

SCRIPTS for TABLES:

```
 CREATE TABLE "MYDB"."USER_REGION_MAPPING" 
   (    "USER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REGION_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STATUS" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
}


CREATE TABLE "MYDB"."USER_DETAILS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "LOGIN_ID" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "EMAIL_ID" VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REGION_CODE" NUMBER, 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "MIDDLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "IS_PRIMARY" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
}

 CREATE TABLE "MYDB"."REGIONS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "IS_DEFAULT" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" NUMBER, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_DATE" DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
insert into User_Region_mapping
(fieldlist)
select (fieldlist)
from USER_DETAILS, REGIONS
where USER_DETAILS.STATUS = 1
  and REGIONS.STATUS = 1
  and not exists (select *
                   from USER_REGION_MAPPING
                   where USER_DETAILS.id = USER_REGION_MAPPING.USER_ID 
                   and USER_DETAILS.id 
                              = USER_REGION_MAPPING.REGION_ID= REGIONS.ID)
```

Syntax may not be perfect but it gives you the idea.

Comment: What about user status = 1 and set all region-user-mapping status to 1?

Comment: add that into the outer where clause.